# How to get String content of Document object(including markup)?

Tags: android, xml, text, document

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.newDocument();

//here append some children....
(this application should run on andoroid API 4)
the problem is : how can I get the text content(including markup) of the "doc" ?
I will appreciated if someone can give me some advice. Thanks~!

Answer (score 4):

```
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    t.transform(new DOMSource(d), new StreamResult(sw));
    System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my application run on the API 4 platform while the class of "TransformerFactory" require API 8 or higher. so, could you have any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Huh? APi 4, API 8, are we talking Android? Maybe you should tag it as such.